# Using Kotlin to query a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, kotlin

I'm trying to understand how to query my postgresql database using Kotlin.

I've tried the following but it looks like I'm not quite understanding how it should be done.

```
interface UserRoleRepository : JpaRepository<UserRole, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM lookup_user_roles WHERE name= :name")
    fun findRoleByName(@Param("name") name: String): UserRole?
}
```

But this just comes out in a massive error.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: A query exception occurred [SELECT * FROM lookup_user_roles WHERE name= :name]

...

Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:7 no viable alternative at input 'SELECT*'
```

How could I achieve this properly within Kotlin?

Thanks

Comment: When using a native query you need to add parameter `nativeQuery = true` to the `@Query` annotation. Or you can use JPA query if the table `lookup_user_roles` is represented by some `@Entity`.